# PLSQL Procedure to check that a value contains in nested table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have big problem to do a simpl "contains" check. Like in java
collection.contains(x). I tried our EXISTS and MEMBER OF without success.

Here is my procedure so far

```
PROCEDURE merge_custom_fields(s1_cf IN custom_fields_table, s2_cf IN custom_fields_table, r_cf OUT custom_fields_table) AS
  BEGIN
      IF(s1_cf IS NOT NULL AND s1_cf .count>0) THEN
        FOR idx IN s1_cf .first..s1_cf .last
        LOOP
         //---> s1_cf(idx).field_id contains in s2_cf <----
            r_cf .extend;
            r_cf (r_cf .last) := s1_cf (idx);
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END merge_custom_fields;
```

Here additional information

```
create or replace TYPE custom_fields_table FORCE
IS
  TABLE OF custom_fields_struct ;
```

And here the definition of custom_fields_struct

```
create or replace TYPE custom_fields_struct FORCE
AS
OBJECT
(
 field_id VARCHAR2 (128 CHAR),
 field_value TIMESTAMP (3)) FINAL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all you want is to get the elements with common `field_id`, You could make use of `TABLE` function and joins.

```
DECLARE

     l_field_value   TIMESTAMP := systimestamp;
     s1_cf           custom_fields_table := custom_fields_table(
     custom_fields_struct(1,l_field_value),custom_fields_struct
     (2,l_field_value) );
     s2_cf           custom_fields_table := custom_fields_table(
     custom_fields_struct(2,l_field_value),custom_fields_struct
     (3,l_field_value) );
     r_cf  custom_fields_table;
BEGIN

SELECT custom_fields_struct(s1.field_id,s1.field_value) --should convert it to object
  BULK COLLECT INTO r_cf --load directly into your OUT collection
FROM   TABLE ( s1_cf ) s1
  JOIN TABLE ( s2_cf ) s2 
ON s1.field_id = s2.field_id; -- This filters the common elements

for i in r_cf.first..r_cf.last 
LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(r_cf(i).field_id||','||r_cf(i).field_value);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

2,18-01-19 06:27:55.607 PM


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

`EXISTS` and and `MEMBER OF` can be used, but I suppose you want to do column to column comparison and not element-wise. So, only other option I can think of is to run a for loop on both the collections and compare the `field_id` of one with another to get the index of the field. But, considering your requirement, the above option should be good enough.

Your procedure would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_custom_fields (
     s1_cf   IN custom_fields_table,
     s2_cf   IN custom_fields_table,
     r_cf    OUT custom_fields_table
)
     AS
BEGIN
     SELECT custom_fields_struct(s1.field_id,s1.field_value) BULK COLLECT
     INTO r_cf
       FROM TABLE ( s1_cf ) s1
     JOIN   TABLE ( s2_cf ) s2 ON s1.field_id = s2.field_id;
END merge_custom_fields;
/
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=affb09f04d8af498e6c050fb0e24eb5f)

Answer (score 0):

may be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_custom_fields (
     s1_cf   IN custom_fields_table,
     s2_cf   IN custom_fields_table,
     r_cf    OUT custom_fields_table
)
     AS
BEGIN
     r_cf := s1_cf MULTISET UNION s2_cf;
END merge_custom_fields;
/
```

[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/m9g1u8)
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3133809066c63d2aaae7080883f0c264)

Comment: As far as question is concerned, OP is definitely not interested in `MULTISET UNION`. They want to compare a column to column (field_id) of two arrays.

Comment: calling function "merge" not compare

Comment: if field_id is unique key and there are only tow values in array can be better to use:
create or replace TYPE custom_fields_table FORCE
IS
  TABLE OF TIMESTAMP INDEX BY VARCHAR2(128) ;